# How to optimize C-code with SSE-intrinsics for packed 32x32 => 64-bit multiplies, and unpacking the halves of those results for (Galois Fields)

Tags: c, optimization, x86, sse, simd

I've been struggling for a while with the performance of the network coding in an application I'm developing (see [Optimzing SSE-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794941/optimzing-sse-code), [Improving performance of network coding-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737488/improving-performance-of-network-coding-encoding) and [OpenCL distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751019/opencl-distribution)). Now I'm quite close to achieve acceptable performance. This is the current state of the innermost loop (which is where >99% of the execution time is being spent):

```
while(elementIterations-- >0)
{   
    unsigned int firstMessageField = *(currentMessageGaloisFieldsArray++);
    unsigned int secondMessageField = *(currentMessageGaloisFieldsArray++);
    __m128i valuesToMultiply = _mm_set_epi32(0, secondMessageField, 0, firstMessageField);
    __m128i mulitpliedHalves = _mm_mul_epu32(valuesToMultiply, fragmentCoefficentVector);
}
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to further optimize this? I understand that it's hard to do without more context but any help is appreciated!

Comment: Before you start in on this kind of hand-work it is worthwhile seeing if your compiler can be talked into doing it for you. Read [Felix von Leitner's presentation (PDF lnk!)](http://www.linux-kongress.org/2009/slides/compiler_survey_felix_von_leitner.pdf) from 2009. Gcc 4.3+ especially is very good at that kind of thing.

Comment: Money quote from the above: *"Note: gcc is smarter than the video codec programmer on all platforms."*

Comment: This loop is in a lot better shape than the one in your other question. But I can still see a few places where the compiler is being idiotic. I'm too tired to give a proper answer now, so I'll do it tomorrow if nobody beats me to it.

Comment: @Mysticial lucky for you that you were tired, because I'll probably make it a bounty tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Now that I'm awake, here's my answer:**

In your original code, the bottleneck is almost certainly `_mm_set_epi32`. This single intrinsic gets compiled into this mess in your assembly:

```
633415EC  xor         edi,edi  
633415EE  movd        xmm3,edi  
...
633415F6  xor         ebx,ebx  
633415F8  movd        xmm4,edi  
633415FC  movd        xmm5,ebx  
63341600  movd        xmm0,esi  
...
6334160B  punpckldq   xmm5,xmm3  
6334160F  punpckldq   xmm0,xmm4 
...
63341618  punpckldq   xmm0,xmm5
```

**What is this? 9 instructions?!?!?!** Pure overhead...

Another place that seems odd is that the compiler didn't merge the adds and loads:

```
movdqa      xmm3,xmmword ptr [ecx-10h]
paddq       xmm0,xmm3
```

should have been merged into:

```
paddq       xmm0,xmmword ptr [ecx-10h]
```

I'm not sure if the compiler went brain-dead, or if it actually had a legitimate reason to do that... Anyways, it's a small thing compared to the `_mm_set_epi32`.

**Disclaimer:** The code I will present from here on violates strict-aliasing. But non-standard compliant methods are often needed to achieve maximum performance.

---

**Solution 1: No Vectorization**

This solution assumes `allZero` is really all zeros.

The loop is actually simpler than it looks. Since there isn't a lot of arithmetic, it might be better to just not vectorize:

```
//  Test Data
unsigned __int32 fragmentCoefficentVector = 1000000000;

__declspec(align(16)) int currentMessageGaloisFieldsArray_[8] = {10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17};
int *currentMessageGaloisFieldsArray = currentMessageGaloisFieldsArray_;

__m128i currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments_[8];
__m128i *currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments = currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments_;
memset(currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments,0,8 * sizeof(__m128i));


int elementIterations = 4;

//  The Loop
while (elementIterations > 0){
    elementIterations -= 1;

    //  Default 32 x 32 -> 64-bit multiply code
    unsigned __int64 r0 = currentMessageGaloisFieldsArray[0] * (unsigned __int64)fragmentCoefficentVector;
    unsigned __int64 r1 = currentMessageGaloisFieldsArray[1] * (unsigned __int64)fragmentCoefficentVector;

    //  Use this for Visual Studio. VS doesn't know how to optimize 32 x 32 -> 64-bit multiply
//    unsigned __int64 r0 = __emulu(currentMessageGaloisFieldsArray[0], fragmentCoefficentVector);
//    unsigned __int64 r1 = __emulu(currentMessageGaloisFieldsArray[1], fragmentCoefficentVector);

    ((__int64*)currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments)[0] += r0 & 0x00000000ffffffff;
    ((__int64*)currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments)[1] += r0 >> 32;
    ((__int64*)currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments)[2] += r1 & 0x00000000ffffffff;
    ((__int64*)currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments)[3] += r1 >> 32;

    currentMessageGaloisFieldsArray     += 2;
    currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments += 2;
}
```

Which compiles to this on x64:

```
$LL4@main:
mov ecx, DWORD PTR [rbx]
mov rax, r11
add r9, 32                  ; 00000020H
add rbx, 8
mul rcx
mov ecx, DWORD PTR [rbx-4]
mov r8, rax
mov rax, r11
mul rcx
mov ecx, r8d
shr r8, 32                  ; 00000020H
add QWORD PTR [r9-48], rcx
add QWORD PTR [r9-40], r8
mov ecx, eax
shr rax, 32                 ; 00000020H
add QWORD PTR [r9-24], rax
add QWORD PTR [r9-32], rcx
dec r10
jne SHORT $LL4@main
```

and this on x86:

```
$LL4@main:
mov eax, DWORD PTR [esi]
mul DWORD PTR _fragmentCoefficentVector$[esp+224]
mov ebx, eax
mov eax, DWORD PTR [esi+4]
mov DWORD PTR _r0$31463[esp+228], edx
mul DWORD PTR _fragmentCoefficentVector$[esp+224]
add DWORD PTR [ecx-16], ebx
mov ebx, DWORD PTR _r0$31463[esp+228]
adc DWORD PTR [ecx-12], edi
add DWORD PTR [ecx-8], ebx
adc DWORD PTR [ecx-4], edi
add DWORD PTR [ecx], eax
adc DWORD PTR [ecx+4], edi
add DWORD PTR [ecx+8], edx
adc DWORD PTR [ecx+12], edi
add esi, 8
add ecx, 32                 ; 00000020H
dec DWORD PTR tv150[esp+224]
jne SHORT $LL4@main
```

**It's possible that both of these are already faster than your original (SSE) code...** On x64, Unrolling it will make it even better.

---

**Solution 2: SSE2 Integer Shuffle**

This solution unrolls the loop to 2 iterations:

```
//  Test Data
__m128i allZero = _mm_setzero_si128();
__m128i fragmentCoefficentVector = _mm_set1_epi32(1000000000);

__declspec(align(16)) int currentMessageGaloisFieldsArray_[8] = {10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17};
int *currentMessageGaloisFieldsArray = currentMessageGaloisFieldsArray_;

__m128i currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments_[8];
__m128i *currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments = currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments_;
memset(currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments,0,8 * sizeof(__m128i));


int elementIterations = 4;

//  The Loop
while(elementIterations > 1){   
    elementIterations -= 2;

    //  Load 4 elements. If needed use unaligned load instead.
    //      messageField = {a, b, c, d}
    __m128i messageField = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)currentMessageGaloisFieldsArray);

    //  Get into this form:
    //      values0 = {a, x, b, x}
    //      values1 = {c, x, d, x}
    __m128i values0 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(messageField,216);
    __m128i values1 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(messageField,114);

    //  Multiply by "fragmentCoefficentVector"
    values0 = _mm_mul_epu32(values0, fragmentCoefficentVector);
    values1 = _mm_mul_epu32(values1, fragmentCoefficentVector);

    __m128i halves0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(values0, allZero);
    __m128i halves1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(values0, allZero);
    __m128i halves2 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(values1, allZero);
    __m128i halves3 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(values1, allZero);


    halves0 = _mm_add_epi64(halves0, currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments[0]);
    halves1 = _mm_add_epi64(halves1, currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments[1]);
    halves2 = _mm_add_epi64(halves2, currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments[2]);
    halves3 = _mm_add_epi64(halves3, currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments[3]);

    currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments[0] = halves0;
    currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments[1] = halves1;
    currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments[2] = halves2;
    currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments[3] = halves3;

    currentMessageGaloisFieldsArray     += 4;
    currentUnModdedGaloisFieldFragments += 4;
}
```

**which gets compiled to this (x86):** (x64 isn't too different)

```
$LL4@main:
movdqa    xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [esi]
pshufd    xmm0, xmm1, 216               ; 000000d8H
pmuludq   xmm0, xmm3
movdqa    xmm4, xmm0
punpckhdq xmm0, xmm2
paddq     xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [eax-16]
pshufd    xmm1, xmm1, 114               ; 00000072H
movdqa    XMMWORD PTR [eax-16], xmm0
pmuludq   xmm1, xmm3
movdqa    xmm0, xmm1
punpckldq xmm4, xmm2
paddq     xmm4, XMMWORD PTR [eax-32]
punpckldq xmm0, xmm2
paddq     xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [eax]
punpckhdq xmm1, xmm2
paddq     xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [eax+16]
movdqa    XMMWORD PTR [eax-32], xmm4
movdqa    XMMWORD PTR [eax], xmm0
movdqa    XMMWORD PTR [eax+16], xmm1
add       esi, 16                   ; 00000010H
add       eax, 64                   ; 00000040H
dec       ecx
jne       SHORT $LL4@main
```

Only slightly longer than the non-vectorized version for two iterations. This uses very few registers, so you can further unroll this even on x86.

---

**Explanations:**

- As Paul R mentioned, unrolling to two iterations allows you to combine the initial load into one SSE load. This also has the benefit of getting your data into the SSE registers.
- Since the data starts off in the SSE registers, `_mm_set_epi32` (which gets compiled into about ~9 instructions in your original code) can be replaced with a single `_mm_shuffle_epi32`.

Comment: +1: nice - this is pretty much what I had in mind but you've actually gone further and done a decent implementation

Comment: @Mysticial you are awesome! It worked on the first try and the SSE-version was almost twice as fast! I'm incredibly impressed by your skills and thankful for your work!

Comment: Why the hell is MSVC using one-operand `mul rcx` instead of the more-efficient `imul rax, rcx`.  It's not using the RDX high half, so why spend an extra uop to make the CPU calculate it?  Or since it already wants the 64-bit result split into two 32-bit results zero-extended separately to 64-bit, use `mul ecx` to do that (into RDX and RAX) because we know the high half of the input is zero.  Oh well, this was MSVC from 2011.  But it's a good example of stupid compilers missing optimizations as well as using lots of redundant `mov` even to implement what it is doing.

Comment: SSE4.1 `pmovzxdq` would save the couple `movdqa` instructions that copy a vector before destructively unpacking the high half.  (so copy-and-zext to another reg, then destructively `punpckhdq` into the multiply result register).  `pshufd` for copy-and-shuffle of the input is nicely avoiding extra `movdqa` there, because `pmuludq` ignores the part of the register.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you unroll your loop by a factor of 2 so that you can load 4 messageField values using one _mm_load_XXX, and then unpack these four values into two vector pairs and process them as per the current loop. That way you won't have a lot of messy code being generated by the compiler for _mm_set_epi32 and all your loads and stores will be 128 bit SSE loads/stores. This will also give the compiler more opportunity to schedule instructions optimally within the loop.

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler unroll it?

Comment: @phakler: compiler loop unrolling tends to be rather unintelligent - the point of loop unrolling here would be to enable the use of vector loads rather than scalar loads - any efficiencies gained from the loop unrolling itself would just be a further bonus

Comment: @Paul R: I've been lead to believe GCC unrolls in part to enable better vectorization. The question was also a bit rhetorical, the compiler *should* do this but apparently does not.